# Django send excel file to Celery Task. Error InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: django, celery

I have background process - read excel file and save data from this file. I need to do read file in the background process. But i have error `InMemoryUploadedFile`.
My code

```
def create(self, validated_data):
   company = ''
   file_type = ''
   email = ''
   file = validated_data['file']

            import_data.delay(file=file,
                                       company=company,
                                       file_type=file_type,
                                       email=email)
```

my method looks like

```
@app.task
def import_data(
        file,
        company,
        file_type,
        email):
// some code
```

But i have error `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

How i can to send a file to cellery without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delay a task, Celery will try to serialize the parameters which in your case a file is included.

Files and especially files in memory can't be serialized.

So to fix the problem you have to save the file and pass the file path to your delayed function and then read the file there and do your calculations.

Comment: It would ideally be saved to some shared file-system where all Celery nodes have access to... In general (this is in Celery docs too if I remember), people should try to avoid passing large objects even if they CAN be serialized because these objects are kept by default for quite some time in Celery...

Answer (score 1):

Celery does not know how to serialize complex objects such as file objects. However, this can be solved pretty easily. What I do is to encode/decode the file to its Base64 string representation. This allows me to send the file directly through Celery.

The following example shows how (I intendedly placed each conversion separatedly, though this could be arranged in a more pythonic way):

```
import base64
import tempfile

# (Django, HTTP server)
file = request.FILES['files'].file
file_bytes = file.read()
file_bytes_base64 = base64.b64encode(file_bytes)
file_bytes_base64_str = file_bytes_base64.decode('utf-8') # this is a str

# (...send string through Celery...)

# (Celery worker task)
file_bytes_base64 = file_bytes_base64_str.encode('utf-8')
file_bytes = base64.b64decode(file_bytes_base64)

# Write the file to a temporary location, deletion is guaranteed
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
    tmp_file = os.path.join(tmp_dir, 'something.zip')
    with open(tmp_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file_bytes)
    # Process the file
```

This can be inefficient for large files but it becomes pretty handy for small/medium sized temporary files.